# This JavaScript code should run indefinitely until an empty string is provided, but it doesn't. Why?

Tags: javascript

```
let yourName;
do {
  yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!yourName);
console.log(yourName);
```

This code is given in an online textbook here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html

I have also tried to run it in console in this way:

```
let funGame;
do { 
    funGame = prompt("enter anything to get rid of this Game");
} while (!funGame); 
console.log(funGame);
```

I am using google chrome browser to test this code. This code just runs once, while it should run indefinitely until an empty string is provided.

Comment: are you trying to use this in a game ? or you just stumbled upon it while learning ?

Comment: _"This JavaScript code should run indefinitely until an empty string is provided"_ - That's not true. From the linked page: _"This program will force you to enter a name. It will ask again and again **until it gets something that is not an empty string**."_ - And that's exactly how it works.

Comment: @سعيد Just stumbled upon while learning.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, I understood now. It will run again and again if I enter an empty string, but will stop running when I enter any string. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The "Do While" works until the condition is true. In your case the code wants that you must write a name to exit from the "do while".

```
let yourName;
do {
  yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!yourName);
console.log(yourName);
```

If you don't want this situation but another you can delete the "!" in the "Do while"

```
let yourName;
    do {
      yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
    } while (yourName);
    console.log(yourName);
```

In this case you get the opposite situation.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution , `yourName != null` checks whether prompt was canceled or not

```js
let yourName;
do {
  yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (yourName != "" && yourName != null);
console.log(yourName);
```

Comment: OPs script works exactly as it should (and your condition doesn't do anything different than what `!yourName` would do)

Comment: no it will be different try removing  ``` yourName !=  ``` null and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the string and run the loop till `yourName` finds a blank content.

```js
do {
  var yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
  console.log(yourName);
  if (!yourName){
    break;
  }
} while (yourName.trim().length > 0);
```